# Can you recommend a free AI tool to search a long list of PDFs with simple queries?

Tags: natural-language-understanding

I'm planning to use AI for a research project on health data. At my organisation, there is a huge quantity of detailed patient reports in PDF format (written in German) that contain unstructured data, which I would like to analyse. Essentially, I would like to run queries along the lines of "when did symptom X first appear?" in a given list of patients.

My question: Can you recommend an easily customisable language tool that is available for research purposes and does not require specialist knowledge to run (i.e. a person with basic coding skills in e.g. Python can learn to use it in a matter of weeks)? For confidentiality reasons, it would be best if the tool could be run locally and not on an external server. Thanks!

(P.S. Please let me know if there's a more suitable forum to ask this kind of question).